# how to show Feedback link in footer. now how to show popup window alert when click on Submit Feedback

Tags: custom-object, standard-objects, design

How to show Feedback link in footer. Now how to show popup window alert when click on Submit Feedback.

VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="WorkFeedback" extensions="FeedBackController" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Feedback Form" rendered="{!Hide}">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" >               
                <apex:inputField value="{!WorkFeedback.Feedback}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!Save}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="self.close()"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!Show}">
            <center> Your feedback has been successfully submitted.
                Thank you for leaving feedback.
                Your contribution is valued and appreciated. </center>
            <apex:commandButton value="Ok" onclick="self.close()"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class FeedBackController {    
    public ApexPages.StandardController con;
    public Boolean Hide{get;set;}
    public Boolean Show{get;set;}

    public FeedBackController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        con=controller;
        Hide=true;
        Show=false;
    }

    public PageReference save() {
        con.save();
        Hide=false;
        Show=true;
        return null;   
    }    
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?Its important to make an attempt before directly pasting requirement here

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your question is the very last part, labelled "Note:" then I would consider using the case object and customising the picklist values available to make them fit the use case better. If you already use cases for other areas then you may want to consider record types, but if you really want to keep everything separate then a custom object would be the next logical step.

Comment: I need separate object for Feedback functionality (Community Users).
My concern only, how to build mentioned requirements in SFDC application.
What would be approach for same?

Comment: That part of the question is way too open ended for SFSE. You should start trying to build it and then post specific questions when you get stuck or hit issues. If you post this to the developer boards you'll get more guidance as that has a less specific format.